# (swift) set long press to -= 1 but now number goes down twice

Tags: ios, swift

So I have my long press recognizer set as follows:

```
    @IBAction func p1s1scoreLongTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        p1s1currentscore -= 1
        p1s1scoreoutlet.setTitle(String(p1s1currentscore), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
```

But now when you long press the button it changes the p1s1current score down two points, once when the duration of the long press is met, and another when lifting finger. How do I remedy this problem?

Comment: Is this `p1s1scoreLongTouch` method meant to handle a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`? If so, you need to read the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer`. The signature is wrong and you need to handle the recognizer's state.

Comment: @rmaddy yes `p1s1scoreLongTouch` is handling the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. The code, when activated by a button to do += 1 works so I (wrongly) assumed you could recycle the code for the long press. I will read up on some documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not taking into account the fact that your gesture recognizer action handler can (and almost surely will) be called multiple times in the course of a single gesture. You need to look at the gesture recognizer's `state` and decide whether you want to perform your decrement for this particular state. (The gesture recognizer is arriving as `sender`, but you are just ignoring it — foolishly.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. After learning I was using the wrong syntax I did some research and my updated code looks more like

```
    @IBAction func p1s1scoreLongTouch(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state == .began {
            print("UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan")
            p1s1currentscore -= 1
            p1s1scoreoutlet.setTitle(String(p1s1currentscore), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        else if sender.state == .ended {
            print("UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded")
        }

    }
```

Still not sure if this is the correct syntax but I know it is more correct since it works.

Comment: That's great but I fail to see how it differs from what I said to do.

Comment: @matt My answer shows the actual answer whereas yours led me in the right direction to find the answer. Feel free to copy the code and update your answer and I'll set your response as the answer.

Comment: I shall do no such thing. Do not dictate to me how to write an answer.  I don't have to write your code for you. I told you exactly what you needed to know. I explained exactly the source of the trouble and how to fix it. No one is going to help you on Stack Overflow if you do not accept answers.

Comment: @matt I have accepted yours as the answer, all I meant was that an example would've been nice. Even something as simple as `if sender.state == .began {}`. I didn't add my code to accept mine as the answer it was to give an example to another passerby who might have the same problem.

Comment: I've supplied oodles of examples. Here's one that shows an implementation of a UILongPressGestureRecognizer action handler: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch05p206gestureRecognizerDelegate/ch18p547gestureRecognizerDelegate/ViewController.swift